# Using the same primary keys across multiple tables

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, foreign-keys, entity

I'm new to creating a database from scratch in postgres.

For a user signing up to a website, the two entities are 'user' (their details) and 'user_pswrd' (to store the users password - which would eventually be encrypted).

My question is, should I create the same Primary Key in both tables:

```
CREATE TABLE user (user_name VARCHAR PRIMARY KEY,
                   first_name VARCHAR,
                   surname VARCHAR,
                   email VARCHAR);

CREATE TABLE user_pswrd (user_name VARCHAR PRIMARY KEY,
                         pswrd VARCHAR)
```

or a Primary Key in 'user' and just reference a Foreign Key in 'user_pswrd':

```
CREATE TABLE user (user_name VARCHAR PRIMARY KEY,
                   first_name VARCHAR,
                   surname VARCHAR,
                   email VARCHAR);

CREATE TABLE user_pswrd (pswrd VARCHAR,
                         FOREIGN KEY(user_name) REFERENCES user(user_name))
```

If none of these are correct, any advice will be appreciated.

Comment: When & how to declare a PK is a faq. Before considering posting please read the manual & google any error message or many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular strings/names & site:stackoverflow.com & tags; read many answers. If you post a question, use one phrasing as title. Reflect your research. See [ask] & the voting arrow mouseover texts. "any advice" is not a valid SO question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two separate tables.  You should have automatic primary keys and use that to connect them:

```
CREATE TABLE users (
    user_id int generated always as identity primary key,  -- in older versions, "serial"
    user_name VARCHAR unique,
    first_name VARCHAR,
    surname VARCHAR,
    email VARCHAR
);

CREATE TABLE user_password (
    user_id int primary key,
    password varchar,
    foreign key (user_id) references users(user_id)
 );
```

Notes:

- There is no reason to store the password in a separate table, unless you have a business reason for doing so.  This appears to be a 1-1 relationship.
- You should NEVER be storing a plaintext password in your application.  In fact, your application should never even see such a password.  The encryption should be on the client side.
- I'm uncomfortable with leaving the lengths off of `varchar`, but Postgres supports that.
- There is no reason to corrupt the name of something like "password".  Just type the whole word.  In the modern world, there are no advantages to using "pswrd".

Comment: Great thanks for your help. It came up with the error: there is no unique constraint matching given keys for referenced table 'users', so I added UNIQUE after 'as identity'.

Comment: @d789w . . . I fixed the constraints.